# how to solve the postfix and prefix operator expression?

Tags: c, logical-operators, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I wrote the following code:

```
int main(){

int i=-1,j=-1,k=0,l=2,m;
m = i++ && j++ && k++ || l++;
printf("%d %d %d %d %d",i,j,k,l,m);

i=-1,j=-1,k=0,l=2,m;
m = ++i && ++j && ++k || ++l;
printf("\n%d %d %d %d %d",i,j,k,l,m);
    return(0);
}
```

and i got the following result:

```
    0 0 1 3 1

    0 -1 0 3 1
```

as i know postfix and prefix operators are solved after the semicolon,ie. the original values are used in the expression and then the variables resolve themselves.
In that case

```
     i++ && j++
```

should be equal to

```
      ++i && ++j
```

and both should be equivalent to

```
     i && j;
     i = i+1;
     j = j+1;
```

and hence the result for the two expressions must be same.
but it is not so.
please anyone can help me with where do i have a wrong concept.

Comment: If you have `int i = 0;`, then the value of `++i` is 1 and the value of `i++` is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i++ && j++` is definitely *not* equivalent to `++i && ++j`.

Take the case where both are zero - the first results in:

```
0 && j++
```

yielding a 0 result (and because of short-circuiting, j won't even get incremented).

In the second case, you'll get

```
1 && 1
```

yielding a 1 result.

With that in mind, let's look at your examples (spaces, semicolons and newlines added for readability):

1. First up:

   ```
   int i = -1;
   int j = -1;
   int k =  0;
   int l =  2;
   int m = i++ && j++ && k++ || l++;
   ```

   Let's first parenthesize completely to make it easier to deal with:

   ```
   int m = ((i++ && j++) && k++) || l++;
   ```

   So, what's going to happen?  First, the `i++`.  `i` is incremented (and becomes `0`), but because it's a *post-increment*, the expression's result is `-1`.  That gives:

   ```
   int m = ((-1 && j++) && k++) || l++;
   ```

   Since the left side of that `&&` is non-zero, the right side is evaluated.  `j++` increments `j` to `0`, but again, post-increment means the expression's value is `-1`.

   ```
   int m = ((-1 && -1) && k++) || l++;
   ```

   Resolve that `&&`:

   ```
   int m = (1 && k++) || l++;
   ```

   Next, the right side of the remaining `&&`.  `k` is incremented, becoming `1`, but the expression yields `0`:

   ```
   int m = (1 && 0) || l++;
   ```

   Resolve this `&&`:

   ```
   int m = 0 || l++;
   ```

   And finally, because the left side of the `||` is 0, the right side is evaluted.  `l` is incremented, becoming `3`, but as a post-increment, yields `2`:

   ```
   int m = 0 || 3;
   ```

   Finally:

   ```
   int m = 1;
   ```

   And along the way we ended up with:

   ```
   i = 0;
   j = 0;
   k = 1;
   l = 3;
   ```

   Explaining your first printout.
2. Next, let's look at the second example (more condensed; let me know if you want more details):

   ```
   int i = -1, j = -1, k = 0, l = 2, m;
   m = ((++i && ++j) && ++k) || ++l;   // parenthesized for readability
          ^                            // i is pre-incremented
   m = (( 0  && ++j) && ++k) || ++l;
              ^                        // first && operator short-circuits
   m = (0 && ++k) || ++l;
           ^                           // second && operator short-circuits
   m = 0 || ++l;
             ^                         // l is pre-incremented
   m = 0 || 3;
          ^                            // evaluate || operator
   m = 1;
   ```

   The results are:

   ```
   i =  0
   j = -1
   k =  0
   l =  3
   m =  1
   ```

   Exactly what you saw printed out.

Comment: for i++ && j++ the expression is evaluated with the old values of i and j and once the expression is evaluated then i and j are updated.
same is the case with ++i && ++j.
I figured the above concept from the note 2 at the bottom of this page:

http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm
if they are different please tell in what order are they solved.

Comment: That table is misleading at best.  Check the `C FAQ` for a better source.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your conditional operator:

```
m=i++&&j++&&k++||l++;
```

The program will start checking the conditional statement (i++ && j++), which equates to (-1 && -1) which comes out true, therefore it continues the statement (true && k++) which means (true && 0) which is false.  It will then check the OR conditional (false || l++) which means (false || 2).  Each time it processed the conditional, the values were incremented via the ++ operator.

The second statement, however...

```
m=++i&&++j&&++k||++l;
```

The program started the conditional (++i && ++j) which equates to (0 && ++j).  It therefore immediately saw the first condition ++i as false and immediately regarded the rest of the block(m=++i&&++j&&++k) as false, not ever processing the ++j or ++k as it did not need to, to determine that the block was going to fail.  It then proceeds to the OR condition (false || ++l) or (false || 3) which is true, m=1.

In the end, the second statement only ever process ++i and ++l, leaving the others un-touched.

I would do a little research on something called "short circuiting", as it is the term that describes why this happens.

Comment: thankyou sir,actually i was mislead with a statement :
Postfix increment/decrement have high precedence, but the actual increment or decrement of the operand is delayed (to be accomplished sometime before the statement completes execution).
I got this on the net.I still could not understand what does it mean but I got my ans. thankyou!